# Android Studio 3.0 Beta freezing constantly on macOS Sierra

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 3.0 Beta keeps freezing several times a day, I launch it via command line to see if there are any traces of whats going and I only get this:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio\ 3.0\ Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/studio ; exit;
2017-09-08 09:01:24.879 studio[2070:19870] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2017-09-08 09:01:24.883 studio[2070:19874] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2017-09-08 09:01:24.883 studio[2070:19874] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2017-09-08 09:01:24.883 studio[2070:19874] Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2017-09-08 09:01:24.883 studio[2070:19874] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2017-09-08 09:01:24.883 studio[2070:19874] Done
2017-09-08 09:01:24.883 studio[2070:19874] Processing VMOptions file at /Users/jsuarez/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview3.0/studio.vmoptions
2017-09-08 09:01:24.883 studio[2070:19874] Done
2017-09-08 09:01:24.883 studio[2070:19874] Processing VMOptions file at 
2017-09-08 09:01:24.885 studio[2070:19874] No content found
/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties: 'java.endorsed.dirs' already defined
Killed: 9
logout
-n Saving session...
-ne 
...saving history...
-n truncating history files...
-ne 
...
completed.
```

This is the report that my mac creates after I have to kill Android Studio

https://gist.github.com/TechFreak/a1a8d14f3f190f45be63b14d3247d5d0

I created a ticket on Google's tracker a while ago but have had no luck either on that: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62824395

Comment: Same happens to me on windows, it actually freezes the whole computer and I have to restart it. It seems to happen when AS is left running for long periods of times for me

Comment: Using IntelliJ Community 2017.2.4 without issues so far

Comment: `File - Invalidate caches & restart`

Comment: thanks @azizbekian but I've already tried that with no luck

Comment: Next time it happens use Activity Monitor's "Sample" feature to get a snapshot of what all the threads are doing. It may offer a clue or two.

Comment: @ReubenScratton Got this https://gist.github.com/TechFreak/fa592ac16f925e35890c9e560b723970

Comment: The modules list in that says "com.google.android.studio (2.3 - AI-162.4069837)", i.e. not the 3.0 beta

Comment: Oh I see you switched back to 2.3. Well the main thread isn't stuck afaics, it seems to be waiting in it's event loop, which is completely normal. Was it definitely "stuck" at the time of the sample?

Comment: spinning beach ball for more than 15 minutes, only thing that I could do was move the window from the title bar, other than that completely unresponsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

1. Remove all Android Studio's.
2. Install JUST Android Studio 2.3.3 stable.

*Note*: check your oracle jdk version, Im using `1.8.0_131` but it looks like with `1.8.0_144` works too.

Comment: Got a similar freeze https://gist.github.com/TechFreak/fa592ac16f925e35890c9e560b723970

Comment: @JulianSuarez what java version do you use? Mine is `javac 1.8.0_131`

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0_144, but AS uses its own version which for AS 2.3 is 1.8.0_112

Comment: Using a different version of Java seems to have solved the issue 1.8.0_144 (Oracle)